# javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Tags: java, email

I have java program(Copied from google) to send emails using office365 SMTP, it is working fine as a stand java program but when I deploy this java program as jar file in `web-inf/lib` of a web application and calling the method from JSP it is throwing the below error:

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;   nested exception is:
javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not
authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
```

Can someone please share their views on this issue. The java code :

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class SendEmailUsingSMTP {
    
    
   public static boolean sendEmail(String toAddress, String fromAddress, String userName, String userPassword,String smtpHost, String portNumber, String emailSubject,String emailBody) {
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
       
       Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SendEmailUsingSMTP.class);
       log.info("toAddress : "+toAddress);
       log.info("fromAddress : "+fromAddress);
       log.info("userName : "+userName);
       log.info("userPassword : "+userPassword);
       log.info("smtpHost : "+smtpHost);
       log.info("portNumber : "+portNumber);
       log.info("emailSubject : "+emailSubject);
       log.info("emailBody : "+emailBody);
       
       String to = toAddress;

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = fromAddress;//change accordingly
      final String username = userName;//change accordingly
      final String password = userPassword;//change accordingly

      // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
      String host = smtpHost;

      Properties props = new Properties();
      
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", portNumber);
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", portNumber);

      // Get the Session object.
      SMTPAuthenticator authenticator = new SMTPAuthenticator(username, password);
      props.put("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);


      try {
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
         InternetAddress.parse(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject(emailSubject);

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText(emailBody);

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);

         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

      } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: The smtpHost,portNumber I am using String smtpHost = "smtp.office365.com";
 String portNumber = "587";

Comment: I am facing exactly same isuse...

Answer (score 9):

You can try with the following configuration, as it works for me:

> "mail.smtp.starttls.enable":"true"

Also, I used host:

> host = "Outlook.office365.com"

Hope this helps you or someone else.

Comment: I tried this. But same exception is coming again
530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Comment: @apm This is because the sender is different from the username that you logged in

Answer (score 6):

Setting the `smtp.starttls.enable` to `true` and the host to `smtp.office365.com` solved the similar problem for me.

I tested it with your code using only these 3 properties:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth",true);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",true);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
```

the host: `smtp.office365.com` and I could sent the emails from my account.

The whole function:

```
  public static boolean sendEmail(String toAddress, String fromAddress, String userName, String userPassword,String smtpHost, String emailSubject,String emailBody) {
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.


      String to = toAddress;

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = fromAddress;//change accordingly
      final String username = userName;//change accordingly
      final String password = userPassword;//change accordingly

      // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
      String host = smtpHost;

      Properties props = new Properties();

      props.put("mail.smtp.auth",true);
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",true);
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the Session object.
      SimpleMailAuthenticator authenticator = new SimpleMailAuthenticator(username, password);
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);


      try {
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
         InternetAddress.parse(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject(emailSubject);

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText(emailBody);

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);

         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

      } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    return true;
   }
```

and the authenticator

```
class SimpleMailAuthenticator extends Authenticator {


    String userName;
    String password;
    PasswordAuthentication authentication;

    public SimpleMailAuthenticator(String userName,String password) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;           
        authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return authentication;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if anyone having issue like :---

> javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not
> authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

While using on Linux OS then,just perform steps given below:-
Edit your default Jenkins file using sudo because it's read only file.

```
sudo vim /etc/default/jenkins
```

And add these two lines:--

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true"
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"
```

After editing/appending the file, restart Jenkins.

command:- `sudo /etc/init.d/Jenkins restart`

Now test your configuration, Hope you will get Email was successfully sent.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the below 
X-Mailer as message.setHeader("X-Mailer", "Your application name");